# Decomposing signal using inverse fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I tried following the code on this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/residentmario/signal-decomposition-with-fast-fourier-transforms), and tried to modify for my generated superposition of 3 sine waves. I am trying to decompose them and plot them individually.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft, fftfreq, rfft, irfft, rfftfreq
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import time
style.use('dark_background')
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,2,constrained_layout=False,figsize=(12,6))
t=[]
data=[]
start_time=time.time()
def decompose_into_n_signals(srs,n,t):
    fourier=rfft(srs)
    frequencies=rfftfreq(srs.size,d=2e-2/srs.size)
    out=[]
    for vals in np.array_split(frequencies,n):
        if vals.size==0:
            break
        ft_threshed=fourier.copy()
        ft_threshed[(vals.min()>frequencies)]=0
        ft_threshed[(vals.max()<frequencies)]=0
        # print(ft_threshed)
        if(ft_threshed.size==0):
            break
        out.append(irfft(ft_threshed))
    return out

def animate(self,t,data):
    t.append(time.time()-start_time)
    t=t[-10:]
    data=np.append(data,np.sin(2*np.array(t))+np.sin(3*np.array(t))+np.sin(4*np.array(t)))
    data=data[-10:]
    y=decompose_into_n_signals(data,3,t)

    ax[0][0].clear()
    ax[0][0].set_title('Unfiltered Data')
    ax[0][0].set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax[0][0].set_ylabel('Signal')
    ax[0][0].set_xlabel('Time')
    ax[0][0].plot(t,data)

    ax[0][1].clear()
    ax[0][1].set_title('Signal 1')
    ax[0][1].set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax[0][1].set_ylabel('Signal')
    ax[0][1].set_xlabel('Time')
    # print(len(t),(y[0]).size)
    # print(y[0])
    ax[0][1].plot(t,y[0])

    ax[1][0].clear()
    ax[1][0].set_title('Signal 2')
    ax[1][0].set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax[1][0].set_ylabel('Signal')
    ax[1][0].set_xlabel('Time')
    ax[1][0].plot(t,y[1])

    ax[1][1].clear()
    ax[1][1].set_title('Signal 3')
    ax[1][1].set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax[1][1].set_ylabel('Signal')
    ax[1][1].set_xlabel('Time')
    ax[1][1].plot(t,y[2])

ani=anim.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,fargs=(t,data),interval=10,frames=100)
fig.tight_layout(pad=5.0)
plt.show()
```

But I am facing an error in `irfft(ft_threshed)` step, it gives the error:

```
raise ValueError(f"Invalid number of FFT data points ({n}) specified.")

ValueError: Invalid number of FFT data points (0) specified.
```

I tried to go around cases where `ft_threshed` might be empty, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Can someone help me here?

Comment: “Invalid number of FFT data points (0) specified.” is pretty clear: you are trying to compute the FFT (or inverse) of an array with 0 points. The remainder of the error message, that you didn’t copy-paste here, should tell you exactly in which line of your code this error happens. From there, try to figure out how come the array is empty. Backtrack and try to follow the logic you wrote.

Comment: What is the purpose of animation here? You'd have the same demonstrative value from a static plot and it'd be easier to implement.